# Mounted.cifs with ro option, user still able to touch

Tags: cifs

I got following setup on Debian 7.7:

```
me@PiWi$ sudo mount.cifs -o user=me,ro //192.168.1.101/media/Data/Games ./Games
me@PiWi$ ls ./Games/ 
Afdrukbaar  Console  Dos ScummVm  Windows
me@PiWi$ touch ./Games/Ishouldnbeable
touch: cannot touch `./Games/Ishouldnbeable': Read-only file system
me@PiWi$ ls ./Games/ 
Afdrukbaar  Console  Dos  Ishouldnbeable  ScummVm  Windows
me@PiWi$ stat ./Games/Ishouldnbeable
  File: `./Games/Ishouldnbeable'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 16384  regular empty file
Device: 12h/18d Inode: 8869134991369  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ me)   Gid: ( 1000/ me)
Access: 2014-12-26 04:44:44.968626700 -0600
Modify: 2014-12-26 04:44:44.968626700 -0600
Change: 2014-12-26 04:44:44.968626700 -0600
 Birth: -
```

As you can see I mounted the CIFS as ro but am still able to write to it.
I tried to use the noperm option but it didn't resolve the issue.
How come and how do I fix this...

```
mount | grep Games
```

gives following outup

```
//192.168.1.101/media/Data/Games on /opt/share/Shared/Games type cifs (ro,relatime,sec=ntlm,unc=\\192.168.1.101\media,username=me,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.101,unix,posixpaths,serverino,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,actimeo=1)
```

Comment: can you post `mount | grep Games` ? Which version of unix are you using ?